# My morning's work was finished. passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

The sentences below come from a story. I am wondering about ***was finished***

> My morning's work ***was finished*** and I was free until six o'clock that evening.

Is it a passive voice? I don't think so, but what kind of sentence it is?

Comment: No: "finished" is an adjective here, not a verb, so it's a complex-intransitive clause, not a verbal passive one, where "finished" is a subjective predicative complement. The difference is that with the verbal passive "finished" there would be some explicit or implicit agent, e.g. "my morning's work was finished by my assistant", whereas in the adjectival "finished" there is not.

Comment: Please don't write answers in the comment box. Doing so bypasses the voting procedure. Use comments to suggest improvements or ask for clarification

Comment: @BillJ wow, wait... this is not passive-voice, right! but What is this, an adjective? How? I didn't get it, sorry.

Comment: Yes, an adjective. It denotes a property of "work", not an action that was performed on it by some implicit agent.

Answer (score 1):

> *My morning's work was finished and I was free until six o'clock that*
>   *evening*.

"Finished" is an adjective here, not a verb, so it's not a verbal passive clause but a complex-intransitive one, where "finished" is subjective predicative complement of "be".

The difference is that with the verbal passive "was finished" there would be some explicit or implicit agent, e.g. "my morning's work was finished by my assistant", whereas in the adjectival "finished" there is not.